# Is memory allocated for unused fields in Java?

Tags: java, memory

I'm wondering how the memory allocation works in Java.

I have a `class Duck` with two instance variables `int size` and `String name`. These variables are initialised. Does the memory for these variables get allocated on the heap during run time, if I'm not instantiating this class?

Thanks,
Gene

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several possible scenarios:

- If you are not using a class, then
  the class itself is not loaded in a
  class loader at all.
- If you are using a class, but not
  instantiating it, then instance
  variables are not occupying memory since there is no instance to begin with.
- If you are using a class, and using
  an object which is instance of that
  class, then instance variables are
  using up memory for each instance,
  regardless of whether you use these
  values or not.

Comment: Hi Goran, thanks for the reply. How can I use a class without instantiating it?

Comment: Static field in a class? Synchronize on class's lock?

Comment: Nitpick: The JVM (specifically the JIT compiler) *might* notice that you aren't acutally using the variables and optimize them out. But that's not guaranteed...

Comment: @sleske: Exactly as you said! It *might* but doesn't have to. So, the safest (worst case) assumption is that it wouldn't happen. Also, it's probably a lot harder to notice that fields are unused than it is for local variables.

Answer (score 6):

IF you are not referencing the class `Duck` at all the class isn't even loaded via classloader so the answer is no.

Comment: So, if this is a public class that is not used in his program, but may be used from some other application, memory is allocated only when instance of that class is made?

Comment: Not about instances. The JVM loads your class first time you make a reference to it (not necesary to create an instance here). So if you have `Duck` in a jar a not referencing it ever in your app it won't be loaded.