# Does Java allocate memory for class' fields even if they are not initialised yet?

Tags: java, memory-management

I'm trying to perform a small memory optimisation for my Java game. It is a bit unclear to me how does Java allocate memory when it comes to fields:

```
public class Test {
    private HashMap<String, String> info;

    public Test(boolean createInfo) {
        if (createInfo) {
            info = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }
    }

}
```

As you can observe, the `HashMap` `info` is initialised if you pass `true` to `Test`'s constructor.

**Does `new Test(true)` take up more memory than `new Test(false)`**?

Which leads to the more general question:

**When you create a field in a class, does Java "reserve" the necessary memory for such field in case it is initialised, or will it do nothing until you actually initialise it?**

There is this question: [Is memory allocated for unused fields in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5370319/555690) which seems to be almost exactly what I am looking for, but they seem to be asking what *already **instantiated** fields* that are unused, whereas I am asking for ***uninstantiated*** fields that may or may not be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does `new Test(true)` take up more memory than `new Test(false)`?

Yes.

> When you create a field in a class, does Java "reserve" the necessary memory for such field in case it is initialised, or will it do nothing until you actually initialise it?

There are two things here - the `HashMap` reference, and the `HashMap` object. Both of them require memory. When a class instance is created, memory is allocated for all its instance variable. In case of `int` type field, it will allocate `4` bytes, similarly for a reference, it will allocate some memory for that reference (I don't know exactly how much it is). But surely it will allocate memory for the fields.

Then when you initialize the fields in the constructor, the actual `HashMap` object is created, which will again take up memory to store the object.

Comment: If I remember correctly the reference would be a pointer, so 4 bytes (8 bytes x64)?

Comment: @Rogue No, it's not a pointer, it's a reference. The Java spec very specifically does not address how large they are, and references include class information as well as memory pointers.

Comment: *"very specifically does not address how large they are"* lol

Comment: When you wrote "loading a class" you probably meant "instatiating an object of the class"? You wrote "When a class is loaded, memory is allocated for all its instance variable." I guess this should read either "When an instance of a class is created, memory is allocated for all its instance variable." or "When a class is loaded, memory is allocated for all its class/static variables."

Answer (score 1):

The *field itself* has space for a reference to an object, and that space is allocated when the containing class (`Test`) is instantiated, even if the value placed in that field is `null`. Your example code doesn't create *an extra* object whose reference will go in that field when you pass in `false`.

Comment: Yes I agree about the reference part.Yet the code creates an object on the heap. So, passing true will take up more space (which includes heap space) right?